# Where is the anvil in Lumbridge?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I started playing Oldschool Runescape earlier. I already have some bronze bars to make me a better armorer, but I can't find an anvil to make it.

Is there any anvil in Lumbridge?

According to this website: [RuneScape Wiki](https://runescape.wiki/w/Anvil) there is an anvil right next to the main smithing furnace in Lumbridge but I'm there and can't find any.

[image: Furnance in Lumbridge]

Where is it?

Comment: I could of sworn that there wasn't an Anvil in Lumby when I played nearly 6 years ago, and that the closest was at Varrock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Old School RS is [the 2007 version of Runescape](https://runescape.wiki/w/Old_School_RuneScape) (in fact, the tag states that).  According to the [Lumbridge page on the Wiki](https://runescape.wiki/w/Lumbridge):

Since the update on 24 June 2010, there is an anvil located near the furnace, which is convenient, since players no longer have to run to the Draynor Village sewers or Varrock to train Smithing or make armour/items.

The version of the game you are playing does not have this anvil there since it does not contain this update.  It has everything up until August 10, 2007, with the addition of some other updates that originate from polls that Jagex runs and the players elect to have in the game.  The God Wars Dungeon was also added into Old School RS, as it was not present as of August 10, 2007 (it was released a few weeks later), and a few other miscellaneous things as well.

Edit: As of July 9<sup>th</sup>, 2020, a [rusted anvil](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Rusted_anvil) exists in Lumbridge, right next to the furnace.  However, it can only be used to smith bronze bars.

Comment: It's worth noting that while it started as just being the 2007 version of Runescape, it has since forked off into it's own version of the game, with tonnes of new content that isn't in RS3 or the original version of the game. While this is likely accurate, it's worth noting that OSRS may have been updated to include later features.

Answer (score 2):

There is no anvil in Lumbridge. You can easily find some anvils in Varrock. There is also a bank just a few steps away, and it's low-level-friendly.

Comment: It depends on what version of the game you are playing.  As I've concluded, the anvil is not there for OSR, but it is for RS3 (or NXT - whichever it is called now).

Comment: Agreed, in RS3 there is an anvil in Lumbi. (And a lot of other stuff, which isn't there in OSR)